# snakemake uses different shell/conda enviroment?

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I am using Snakemake in an conda environment. At the beginning of my snakefile I have a "log-Rule", which saves run information. One of those information is which tools are part of the environment (`conda list >> log.file`).

```py
    rule logRule:
        params:
            runID
        output:
            cfgLocation+runID+"_runParams.txt"
        priority: 1
        shell:
            """
            echo {params} >> {output}
            date >> {output}
            cat Snakefile >> {output}
            echo "-----___----____---____---____-----" >> {output}
            conda list >> {output} 
            """
```

Probably not the most elegant way of doing it, but it works in other environments. However, in the current one it says that it can not find the command "conda". However, running `conda list` directly does work fine (same shell session where i also call `snakemake -p --cores 8`.

In looking for the reason I also discovered that the `ll` command (alias to `ls -l`), can not be found as well.

I thought that snakemake uses the currently active conda env and since it works in the env if run directly, I don't even know how to look for a solution.

Any suggestion where this is coming from, and how to resolve that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching snakemake from another tab/window (e.g. in tmux), then it won't inherit the environment and this environment should be activated explicitly before running `snakemake` with `source activate` or `conda activate` (as appropriate).

It's also possible that `snakemake` and `python` were installed outside the environment, which can be checked with `which snakemake` and `which python`. If they point to binaries outside the active environment, it might be necessary to install them inside the active environment.

Perhaps a more robust way is to explicitly specify environments for each rule via `conda` directive (see [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management)). Note that this does require you to specify the environment ahead of time (which might be different from what you are after).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using tmux, however the discrepancy between `snakemake -p --cores 8` and `conda list` does occur in the same tmux session (in which I activated the env with `conda activate <ENV Name>)

Comment: Can you see if `which python` is pointing to your env? And also `which snakemake`?

Comment: both are pointing towards correct env
.../miniconda3/envs/<ENV Name>/bin/snakemake
.../miniconda3/envs/<ENV Name>/bin/python

Comment: I see... hmm, well, it's a hack, but putting an explicit `conda activate` inside the shell directive might work.

Comment: Also, can you check `which conda`?

Comment: `which conda` does not return anything.  And `conda list` within a shell script can not be found as well (with or without a `conda activate` directive). So it seems to be unrelated to snakemake. Do I need to install conda in the environment explicitly?

Comment: No, I never had to install conda inside an environment, but I wanted to check if this could give a clue...